# Citing one's own work in an answer

Tags: discussion

I have written a handful of sport-and-fitness-related articles outside the bounds of *Physical Fitness Stack Exchange*, one of which I have thought would be particularly relevant to a some of the questions asked on this forum. However, I have abstained from citing it, assuming that it would be against the regulations of the forum.

*What is the protocol with regard to citing an article for an answer, when* ***we*** *are the author of that article? Is it against the rules entirely, or are there some circumstances under which it might be acceptable?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perfectly acceptable within reasonable limits, and it's [covered in the FAQ](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) for each site on self promotion -

> Avoid overt self-promotion.

> The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.

> If a large percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons. Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; contact our ad sales team for details. We also offer free community promotion ads for open source projects and non-profit organizations.

So basically, as long as you disclose your affiliation and don't do it too much, it's fine (and encouraged) to cite your own works. You can also add your published works/website in your profile.

And we are glad to have published authors contributing!

Comment: Just as an aside, I checked the metas on physics, math, and a couple others that might have a greater prevalence of published contributors, and they are pretty much the same.